# Load dataframe using spark: Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType

Tags: mongodb, dataframe, apache-spark

```
com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast ARRAY into a StructType(StructField(userid,StringType,true),StructField(username,StringType,true),StructField(zohocrm_id,StringType,true)) (value: BsonArray{values=[]})
```

i got this fault when using spark to load data from mongodb. but when i using $match in .option pipeline it work. how to fix this fault, thanks !

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("mongo4XC") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri",dbURLinfo) \
        .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri",dbURLinfo) \
        .config("spark.executor.heartbeatInterval", "180s") \
        .config("spark.network.timeout", "300s") \
        .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:3.0.2') \
        .config("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000) \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.sampleSize", 500000) \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
        .option("database", db_database) \
        .option("collection", collection) \
        .option("pipeline", pipeline) \
        .load()
```

i want to load full database in mongo not using $match

Answer (score 0):

Error in field 'User' in mongo in some documents are of type Object and the rest are due to lack of data, so they convert themselves to Array type